# Spring batch Cron expression: to run every 3 hours

Tags: spring, cron, spring-batch

I want my spring batch job to run every 3 hours

I used expression `* * */3 * * ?` this starts the job at the hour that is divisible by 3 e.g. say the server was started at 2 PM the job starts executing only at 3 PM - so far so good but the job keeps starting every second! Is it because I used * in the 1st position?

I tried `0 0 */3 * * ?` but it is erroring out. What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 49):

The format is

> second, minute, hour, day, month, weekday

so the correct cron expression should be

```
0 0 */3 * * *
```

If that doesn't work, what's the exact error message you are getting?

Comment: what is the difference between 0/3 and */3?

Comment: what is the difference   0/3 and */3?

Comment: * means every possible value in the field. ? means you don't care about the value. It's used when you have two fields that may contradict each other.

Comment: So I think */3 is every 3 hrs since the server started and 0/3 is every 3 hours where the hour is divisible by 3; so 3am, 6am, 9am, 12am, 3pm, 6pm, 9pm, 12pm. If anyone can confirm that would be great.

Comment: Ok I just ran a job with: 0 0 0/6 * * * to try for every 6 hours and it did work, it seemed to run every 6th whole hour after the server was started. I bounced it at 5:50pm and the job ran at 11pm, 5am, 11am. I would take a guess that */6 would run at exactly every 6 hours after the server was started in this case, 11:50pm, 5:50am and so on. So they both work but 0/6 is the 6th whole hour and */6 is exactly every 6 hours.

Answer (score 19):

The right syntax to make the script to run every 3 hours is as below.

```
0 0 0/3 * * ?
```

Comment: Spring cron jobs require 6 digits instead of 5